# Finding the generator 'identity'... The given assembly name or codebase was invalid

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-identity, dotnet-cli, asp.net-core-scaffolding

My [App](https://github.com/AskYous/IslaamDatabase.Com/tree/error) builds and runs just fine. But when I try to run `dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity --useDefaultUI`, it errors:

> Building project ...
>
> Finding the generator 'identity'...
>
> The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)
>
> at System.Reflection.AssemblyName.nInit(RuntimeAssembly& assembly, Boolean raiseResolveEvent)
>      at System.Reflection.AssemblyName..ctor(String assemblyName)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.DefaultCodeGeneratorAssemblyProvider.b__6_0(DependencyDescription lib)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.CodeGeneratorsLocator.get_CodeGenerators()
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.CodeGeneratorsLocator.GetCodeGenerator(String codeGeneratorName)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.CodeGenCommand.Execute(String[] args)
>   RunTime 00:00:05.76

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solved my issue: https://github.com/aspnet/Scaffolding/issues/586

In short: I had to **remove** this from my .csproj file:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration" Version="1.1.1" />
```